# Different Execution Plans with same date from temp table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

Basically, I have a temp table and I am populating the table with the same data using different techniques in order to find the fastest one in my case. The three methods are:

1. select inserted information using joins
2. select inserted information where most of the
   tables/logic/calculations are included in inline function
3. select inserted information where most of the
   tables/logic/calculations are included in table-value function

With each method the table is populated with the same data and I get best performance using the table value function. But here the things comes strange.

After the temp table is populated a simple SELECT is done over it, with GROUP BY and ORDER BY on all columns. Because the data is the same I have expected same execution plans, but I get this:

[image]

Where the first row is the execution plan of the table-value function and the second one is the execution plan for the first and the second method.

Why I have two different executions plan for table with same data? Why it is not always using the first one as it is faster then the the second one?

Note, as this is connected with data being sorted and grouped by, I have supposed when I use the table-valued function maybe the date is already sorted, but simple select of the results display that the data is sorted in the same way in each case.

Comment: Wow you should have been around in the early days before query optimizer.  The query optimizer can only operate within the structure of the query.   You can still do hints today.  A join, exists, and intersect can all be equivalent queries that will typically have different query plans.

Comment: In this situation I am focused on the last SELECT that's purpose is to  show all records from the temp table using ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses. And as I have the same information, I am expecting the same plans. I am not comparing the first part of the statements where I am using different approaches.

Comment: So unclear.  Your question is about a select statement you did not even post?

Comment: I doubt it would be very useful to show a ordinary select with group by and order by clauses?

Answer (score 0):

There is more to execution plans than data

Take a look at [Only In A Database Can You Get 1000% + Improvement By Changing A Few Lines Of Code](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr)

Something like this is not `SARGAble`  and a sub-optimal plan will be created

```
where year(payment_dt) = year(getDate())
and month(payment_dt) = month(getDate())
```

The optimizer will create an optimal plan for

```
where payment_dt >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+0, 0)
and payment_dt < dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
```

Those two will return the same rows, one will use a seek, the other one a scan because functions are used around the columns